# Finding a composite function

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

Given that
$h(x) = f(g(x))$

$h(x) = \sin(x)$

$f(x) = \cos(x)$

What is the function $g(x)$?

Comment: If $\cos^2 x +\sin^2 x =1$ then...

Comment: Or alternatively, consider a phase shift.

Answer (score 2):

$$h(x) = f(g(x))=\cos (g(x))=\sin x=cos(x-\frac{\pi}{2})$$ so
$ g(x)=2k\pi+x-\frac{\pi}{2}$ or $g(x)=2k\pi-(x-\frac{\pi}{2})$

Comment: Shouldn't it be Pi/2 - x instead?

Comment: @nab331 $\cos -\theta = \cos \theta$ so fortunately, they are the same. Writing it as $x - \frac{\pi}{2}$ instead emphasizes that $g$ shifts the phase of the $f$, i believe.

Comment: Ah. Yes. Thank you.

Comment: Both $x-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2-x$ work. As do $x+3\pi/2$ and $5\pi/2-x$ (we can add any integer multiple of $2\pi$). The answer is not unique, so the implication arrow in this answer should be read as something like "this shows that $g(x)=x-\pi/2$ works" rather than "this shows that $g(x)$ must be equal to $x-\pi/2$", because the latter interpretation is wrong.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I edit it. thank you for your precious comment.

Answer (score 0):

Over a certain set, you could use $g(x)=\cos^{-1}(\sin(x)),$ since then $f(g(x)=\cos(\cos^{-1}(\sin(x)))=\sin(x),$ since the cos and cos inverse cancel.